# Facebook.init() function still causing null exception

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine

**Background:**
I am trying to integrate facebook for a unity-android project and I can't seem to make it working, I have looked on the fb page and allot of other place but can't seem to find a what I am doing wrong.

**Problem:**
When trying FB.Login i get the reference exception: Facebook object is not loaded. Did you call FB.init?

**Code for InitializeFB.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.MiniJSON;
using System;

public class ConncetToFaceBook : MonoBehaviour {



    // Connect to facebook
    void Awake () {
        // Required
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        // Initialize FB SDK
        enabled = false;
        FB.Init(onInitComplete, OnHideUnity);

        //Display id
        Debug.Log (FB.UserId);

        //Login to facebook
        FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
    }


    /* Helper Methods */
    private void onInitComplete ()
    {   
        enabled = true; // "enabled" is a property inherited from MonoBehaviour
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            //Some Code            
        }
    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {

        //some code
    }

    void LoginCallback(FBResult result)                                                        
    {                                                                                          
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)                                                                     
        {                                                                                      
            OnLoggedIn();                                                                      
        }                                                                                      
    }                                                                                          

    void OnLoggedIn()                                                                          
    {                                                                                          
        Debug.Log("Logged in. ID: " + FB.UserId);                                            
    } 
}
```

**Code for FB.cs.init()**

```
public static void Init(
        InitDelegate onInitComplete,
        string appId = "{My app ID}", //I did put my own here. Plus I use " instead of ' because ' give me a error. 
        bool cookie = true,
        bool logging = true,
        bool status = true,
        bool xfbml = true,
        bool frictionlessRequests = true,
        HideUnityDelegate onHideUnity = null,
        string authResponse = null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FB.Init()` is asynchronous method - it doesn't make the program wait until it is finished. And your  `FB.Login()` is called too soon, you need to call it after `FB.Init()` is ready - inside the `onInitComplete()` method.

My setup:

```c#
    void FBConnect(){
        if(!FB.IsInitialized){
            Debug.Log("Initializing FB");
            FB.Init(FBInitCallback, null,null);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("No need for FB init");
            FBInitCallback();       
        }
    }

    private void FBInitCallback(){
        Debug.Log("FB init OK");
        if(!FB.IsLoggedIn){
            FB.Login("email,user_friends", FBLoginCallback);
        } else {        
            //GetHisFBDataNow();
            Debug.Log("Everything is known about this guy");
        }
    }

    private void FBLoginCallback(FBResult result){
        if (result.Error != null){
            Debug.Log("FB Error Response:\n" + result.Error);
        } else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)      {
            Debug.Log("FB Login cancelled by Player");
        } else {
            //GetHisFBDataNow();
            Debug.Log("Now also everything is known about this guy");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Answer is right. Also there are 2 thing you have to consider.. 
1- In Android first check your true KEY HASH by "ddms" or "monitor" (Android SDK Tool). Just after `FB.Init()` call, search "Hash", there you will find the proper KEY HASH for your KeyStore. Paste that KEY HASH to your facebook app at [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com). 2- Facebook Unity has still a bug, you have to call `FB.Init()` every time when you land on login/logout screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hey idk if that will help but can you try and put fb.log in init complete?